# Enter-PSSession from a Debian container

Tags: python, linux, powershell, winrm

I have a Debian container with powershell core installed. When I run powerhsell, and use `Enter-PSSession` to remote to a Windows host, I get the expected result.

I'm trying to launch this interactive remote session from an existing python program which spawns a login command with `subprocess.run()`. The command that gets run is typically ssh, but the login command string is customizable. When I try setting that string to something like `pwsh -i -Command 'Enter-PSSession ...`, the resulting shell just hangs. The exact same invocation of `Enter-PSSession` works fine if i'm already in `pwsh`. Is there anything special I need to do to launch `pwsh` in interactive mode where the command is an interactive session to a remote host?

Comment: `subprocess.run` waits for the subprocess to exit. It sounds like you are painting yourself into a deadlock corner by trying to use it for something interactive.

Comment: `Enter-PSSession` is for interactive use. You want `Invoke-Command`